# Convert der to pem through bouncy castle library

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, x509

I found many answers towards convert from *pem* to *der*.

However, I cannot find ways to convert *der* to *pem*.

for example, the following codes generates der encoded file *pkcs10.cer*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    X509Certificate[] chain = buildChain();
    PEMWriter pemWrt = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    pemWrt.writeObject(chain[0]);

    FileWriter fwO = new FileWriter("pkcs10.cer");
    fwO.write((chain[0]).toString());

    fwO.close();
    pemWrt.close();

}
```

Like,
  [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: 1353995641265
             IssuerDN: CN=Test Certificate
           Start Date: Mon Nov 26 21:54:01 PST 2012
           Final Date: Mon Nov 26 21:54:51 PST 2012

However, I don't know how to make pem encoded Certification from der files.

Comment: This question seems very confused. If you remove the fwO stuff completely from the given example, it would leave essentially code for writing an X509Certificate to System out in PEM format. The fwO parts are NOT producing DER, for that you would need to call getEncoded instead of toString.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not a Java developer, and therefore I cannot show you code or point to a class. PEM is just the Base64 encoding of the binary DER, with a standard header and trailer.

Comment: My apologies @owlstead. I was on my mobile and still can't type well on it.  Just to old skool.

Comment: Yeah, I know that feeling. Maybe edit it when you get home, or type it in later. I can type relatively well on mine but I still haven't found out how I can quickly inline code as the right character is completely missing from the screen keyboard. Rereading and tinkering before posting is certainly required.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a method that will convert various BC objects to PEM string serialized format.  Note this code is for the C# version of BC but should translate to the Java version without much effort.

```
// converts bouncy castle objects of type
// X509Certificate, X509Crl, AsymmetricCipherKeyPair, AsymmetricKeyParameter,
// IX509AttributeCertificate, Pkcs10CertificationRequest, Asn1.Cms.ContentInfo 
// to PEM format string
public string ToPem(object obj)
{
    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(mem);
        Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemWriter pem = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemWriter(writer);
        pem.WriteObject(obj);
        // force the pem write to flush it's data - kind of abnoxious you have to do that
        pem.Writer.Flush();
        // create a stream reader to read the data.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mem);
        mem.Position = 0;
        string pemStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return pemStr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for completeness's sake, this is way you can read binary DER data into a Bouncy Castle `X509Certificate` (where `derData` is the binary DER certificate):

```
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate 
    = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(derData);
```

Using this `X509Certificate` you can no use @Benton's method to the PEM representation:

```
 string pemData = ToPem(certificate);
```