# Convert .der to .pem using Java

Tags: private-key, pem, der

I am attempting to export the contents of a PrivateKey (assumed DER) format into a stream of bytes encoded as PEM format.

The link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835614/5107016) discusses the use of BouncyCastle and PemWriter to dump a key to PEM format.

Is there a way to create a BouncyCastle object from a PrivateKey object, or some other way to export PrivateKey as PEM byte stream?

Comment: PEM is not really a format.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet seems to do the job:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.Instance("JKS");
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("path-to-jks-file");
keystore.load(stream, null);
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("mykey", "password".toCharArray());
byte[] prvkey = key.getEncoded();
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(prvkey);
String key_pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" + encoded + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
```